# PHP Warning: include

Tags: php, laravel

I just downloaded a Laravel script
then I used from it in my local host (wamp) without any problem but now when I want to use from it in my host, it shows: 500 error

error_log file

> [12-Feb-2019 16:59:48 Asia/Tehran] PHP Warning:  include(/home/grammer/public_html/test/core/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> /home/grammer/public_html/test/core/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on
> line 444 [12-Feb-2019 16:59:48 Asia/Tehran] PHP Warning:  include():
> Failed opening
> '/home/grammer/public_html/test/core/vendor/composer/../laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php'
> for inclusion
> (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php72/root/usr/share/pear') in
> /home/grammer/public_html/test/core/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php on
> line 444 [12-Feb-2019 16:59:48 Asia/Tehran] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught
> Error: Class 'Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem' not found in
> /home/grammer/public_html/test/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:175
> Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 /home/grammer/public_html/test/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(144):
>
> Illuminate\Foundation\Application->registerBaseBindings()
>
> ## 1 /home/grammer/public_html/test/core/bootstrap/app.php(15): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->__construct('/home/grammer/p...')
>
> ## 2 /home/grammer/public_html/test/index.php(38): require_once('/home/grammer/p...')
>
> ## 3 {main}   thrown in /home/grammer/public_html/test/core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php
>
> on line 175

Comment: Did you read the Laravel docs on how to create and deploy projects?  Looks like you're skipping composer.

Comment: Yes. but I don't know why this error appeared because I can't find the error

Comment: Run `composer install` in root folder of your project.

Answer (score 1):

```
composer install
```

The error is telling you clearly, missing basically not find vendor which is the base larvel and run the command in the folder of your laravel project and do not forget to configure your .env file eventually

Comment: I don't have access to cmd in host

Comment: I was shocked, because if the project have problem, why it works in wamp without any problem?

Comment: possibly because you created the project there, you will have to ask for access to the console or ask them to execute the command for you, also maybe upload it via git and git ignore the vendor folder, among others, leave the project clean so that later composer will be in charge and lighten the load